# postgresql - SELECT records based on the current time

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently using POSTGRESQL. The rows in my DB are like:

```
course_name | time_start | time_end
CSCI-C110        13:00:00     17:30:00
CSCI-K330        09:00:00     12:00:00
```

See there are columns called "time_start" and "time_end". I'd like to select the record based on the current time (check if the time is in the range of time_start and time_end). For example, if the current time is 15:00, it only returns the first record with course_name because the time is between time_start and time_end. Could anyone please help me out??

Comment: You can use something like `time_start < DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) and time_end >DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post code or sql statements as images. It makes much harder for anyone to answer your question because it is not possible to copy&paste anything from it.

Comment: @Elikill58 Thank you for your information! I don't think it works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, guys! Here is the answer:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (Your table name) 
WHERE time_start > to_char(NOW(),'HH24:MI')::time 
  AND time_end < to_char(NOW(),'HH24:MI')::time
```

Comment: You can simplify `to_char(NOW(),'HH24:MI')::time` to `now()::time` and use between, i.e. `where now()::time between time_start and time_end`